# Problems installing argon2 in a project with npm

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-install

I'm having some issue's installing argon2 npm package in my project. I am a bit of a beginner and have tried to check everything:
To start this is my system:

**MacBook Air m1** 6 months old

**Python
3.10.2**

**Clang
Apple clang version 13.1.6** (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

**Make
GNU Make 3.81**
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

**Installed:
sudo npm install -g node-gyp**
within the package but globally

If I go inside the node-gyp folder:
**node-gyp@9.0.0  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp
node@17.6.0**

So it looks like I have everything to get it running.

After the command for argon2:

**npm i argon2**

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/billy/Wild Code School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express----- 
Quests/node_modules/argon2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/ref.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/argon2.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/core.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/thread.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/encoding.o
npm ERR!   LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/argon2.a
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/argon2/src/argon2_node.o
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build -- 
fallback-to-build --module=/Users/billy/Wild Code 
School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi- 
v3/argon2.node --module_name=argon2 --module_path=/Users/billy/Wild Code 
School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi- 
v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 -- 
node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@17.6.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/billy/Wild Code 
School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi- 
v3/argon2.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/ranisalt/node- 
argon2/releases/download/v0.28.5/argon2-v0.28.5-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on 
https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2/releases/download/v0.28.5/argon2-v0.28.5- 
napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for argon2@0.28.5 and 
node@17.6.0 (node-v102 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on 
https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2/releases/download/v0.28.5/argon2-v0.28.5- 
napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.6.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.6.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/billy/Wild Code 
School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express- 
Quests/node_modules/argon2/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/billy/Library/Caches/node- 
gyp/17.6.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/billy/Library/Caches/node- 
gyp/17.6.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '- 
Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/billy/Library/Caches/node- 
gyp/17.6.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/billy/Wild Code 
School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.6.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Code'
npm ERR! clang: error: no such file or directory: 
'School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/node-addon-api'
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/argon2/src/argon2_node.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
 (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" 
 "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "-- 
 fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/billy/Wild Code 
 School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi- 
 v3/argon2.node" "--module_name=argon2" "--module_path=/Users/billy/Wild Code 
 School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi- 
 v3" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "-- 
 node_napi_label=napi-v3"
 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/billy/Wild Code 
 School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2
 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.6.0
 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node 
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build -- 
 fallback-to-build --module=/Users/billy/Wild Code 
 School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi- 
 v3/argon2.node --module_name=argon2 --module_path=/Users/billy/Wild Code 
 School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi- 
 v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 -- 
 node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/billy/Wild 
 Code School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre- 
 gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose 
 (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
 (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/billy/Wild Code 
 School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" 
 "install" "--fallback-to-build"
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/billy/Wild Code 
 School/Express/MVC_architecture/Express-Quests/node_modules/argon2
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.6.0
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /Users/billy/.npm/_logs/2022-06-10T13_25_52_362Z-debug-0.log
```